Why is Replicate's API returning a empty object instead of the image URL, and how can I process it?
I am working on an AI-powered image generation app using Replicate's API, and I’m using the bytedance/sdxl-lightning-4step model to generate images from prompts. However, when I call the /api/generate-image endpoint I created, the API response give me empty result in console.
Here’s the full behavior:

For testing purpose I am just using a given prompt 'VdoScript' and only calling  GenerateImage methid by clicking the button 'Create Video' using onCreateClickHandler method. So you can ignore the other functions if you want, I am just talking about the GenerateImage() function.

I send a POST request with a prompt to /api/generate-image.
"use client"
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import SelectTopic from './_components/SelectTopic'
import SelectStyle from './_components/SelectStyle';
import SelectDuration from './_components/SelectDuration';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import axios from 'axios';
import CustomeLoading from './_components/CustomeLoading';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const VdoScript = [
    {
        "scene": 1,
        "duration": 5,
        "ContentText": "1799: Napoleon's army discovers a mysterious stone in Egypt.  Inscriptions in three scripts – hieroglyphs, Demotic, and Ancient Greek – hint at unlocking a lost world.",
        "imagePrompt": "Realistic photo of a weathered stone slab with hieroglyphs, Demotic script, and Ancient Greek script clearly visible, partially buried in sand, bright desert sun, Napoleon's soldiers in the background,  cinematic lighting"
      },
]


function CreateNew() {

    const[formData, setFormData] = useState([]);
    const[loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const[videoScript, setVideoScript] = useState();
    const[audioFileUrl, setAudioFileUrl] = useState();
    // saving the captions, words in one state
    const[captions, setCaptions] = useState();
    const[imageList, setImageList] = useState();

    const onHandleInputChange = (fieldName, fieldValue) => {
        console.log(fieldName, fieldValue)

        setFormData(prev=>({
            ...prev,
            [fieldName]:fieldValue
        }))
    }

    const onCreateClickHandler=()=>{
        //GetVideoScript();
        //GenerateAudioFile(ScriptData);
        // GenerateAudioCaption(FILEURL);
        GenerateImage();
    }
    // Get Video Script -- API call
    const GetVideoScript=async ()=>{
        setLoading(true)
        const prompt='Write a script to generate a '+formData.duration+' video on the topic: '+formData.topic+' along with AI image prompt in '+formData.imageStyle+' format for each scene and give me result  in JSON format with image prompt and ContentText as field'
        console.log(prompt)
        const result=await axios.post('/api/get-video-script',{
            prompt:prompt
        }).then(resp=>{
            //console.log(resp.data.result)
            console.log("EXE");
            setVideoScript(resp.data.result); // once scripts is generated
            resp.data.result&&GenerateAudioFile(resp.data.result); // generate the audio file
        })
        //setLoading(false)
        //console.log(result)
    }

    const GenerateAudioFile=async(videoScriptData)=>{
        setLoading(true);
        let script= '';
        const id = uuidv4();
        videoScriptData.forEach(item=>{
            script=script+item.ContentText+' ';
        })
        await axios.post('/api/generate-audio',{
            text:script,
            // for example purpose
            //text:videoScriptData,
            id:id
        }).then(resp=>{
            //console.log(resp.data);
            setAudioFileUrl(resp.data.result);// get file url
            resp.data.result&&GenerateAudioCaption(resp.data.result)
            //setLoading(false);
        })
        // console.log(script);
        //console.log(videoScript, captions, audioFileUrl);
        
    }

    const GenerateAudioCaption=async(fileUrl)=>{

        setLoading(true);
        console.log(fileUrl)
        await axios.post('/api/generate-caption',{
            audioFileUrl:fileUrl
        }).then(resp=>{
            console.log(resp.data.result);
            setCaptions(resp?.data?.result); // generate caption
            GenerateImage();
        })
        
        console.log(videoScript, captions, audioFileUrl);
    }

    /** 
     Used to generate Ai images
    **/
    const GenerateImage=()=>{
        //setLoading(true)
        let images = [];
        // VdoScript for testing...declaired above
        VdoScript.forEach(async(element)=>{
            await axios.post('/api/generate-image',{
                prompt:element?.imagePrompt
            }).then(resp=>{
               console.log(resp.data.result);
               images.push(resp.data.result);
            })
        })
        console.log(images);
        setImageList(images);
        //console.log(imageList)
        setLoading(false);
        
    }

    

  return (
    <div className='mid:px-20'>
        <h2 className='font-bold text-4xl text-primary text-center'>Create New</h2>

        <div className='mt-10 shadow-md p-10'>
            {/* select topic */}
            <SelectTopic onUserSelect={onHandleInputChange}/>

            {/* select style */}
            <SelectStyle onUserSelect={onHandleInputChange}/>

            {/* select duration */}
            <SelectDuration onUserSelect={onHandleInputChange}/>

            {/* create button */}
            <Button className='mt-10 w-full' onClick={onCreateClickHandler}>Create Video</Button>
        </div>

        <CustomeLoading loading={loading}/>

    </div>
  )
}

export default CreateNew


I am calling the API from the path app/api/generate-image/route.jsx: its a model named bytedance/sdxl-lightning-4step (text to image generator ) from replicate.com

import Replicate from "replicate";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { storage } from "@/configs/FirebaseConfig";
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadString } from "firebase/storage";

export  async function POST(req){
    try{
        const {prompt} = await req.json();
        const replicate = new Replicate({
            auth:process.env.REPLICATE_API_TOKEN
        });

        const input = {
            prompt:prompt,
            height:1280,
            weidth:1024,
            num_outputs:1
        };

        const output = await replicate.run("bytedance/sdxl-lightning-4step:5599ed30703defd1d160a25a63321b4dec97101d98b4674bcc56e41f62f35637", { input });
        console.log(output);
        return NextResponse.json({'result':output[0]});

    }catch(e){

    }
}

browser console:

postman (showing empty object) console:

replicate-api dashboard (showing the model is generating the image):

I think that there is a some problem in the GenerateImage() function.
Expected output should be like that:
{
  "result": "https://path-to-generated-image.com/image.png"
}

but I am getting
{
  "result": {}
}

Can anyone help me; what's the problem?
